# Save multiple canvas as one image (make website like PicFrame)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I try to make website like PicFrame app so I found this demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/appsaloon/4jRLM/

I want to use multiple canvas in the demo and save it to one image. How to save all canvas to one images? Sorry for my english, Thanks!

My HTML code is look like this:

```
<div id="container">

    <input type="file" id="imageLoader_1" />
    <canvas id="imageCanvas_2" width="400" height="200"></canvas> 

    <input type="file" id="imageLoader_2" />
    <canvas id="imageCanvas_2" width="400" height="200"></canvas> 

    <a id="imageSaver" href="#">Save image</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `context.drawImage` to draw images on a canvas.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas0');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(myImage,0,0);
```

Since another canvas can be an image source for `drawImage`, you can merge multiple canvases onto a single canvas like this:

```
var canvas1=document.getElementById('canvas1');
var canvas2=document.getElementById('canvas2');
var canvas3=document.getElementById('canvas3');
var canvas4=document.getElementById('canvas4');

// merge 4 canvases (canvas1-canvas4) onto a single canvas
// (this example assumes canvas1-4 are 100x100 -- adjust to your needs)
context.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);
context.drawImage(canvas2,100,0);
context.drawImage(canvas3,0,100);
context.drawImage(canvas4,100,100);
```

Then you can create an image dataURL from the merged canvas using `context.toDataURL`

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Further, you can create an image object using that dataURL

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
img.src=dataURL;
```